# Web Application with Angular 10 errors

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I am trying to create an web application with angular 10. I have some errors that i cant figure out how to solve. Maybe someone can help me with some indications. Here is the code, but i will put that part with problems, not the entire code.

**Typescript file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MineralWorldService } from 'src/app/services/mineral-world.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mineral-list',
  templateUrl: './mineral-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mineral-list.component.css']
})
export class MineralListComponent implements OnInit {

  minerals!: any;



  constructor(private mineralworldService: MineralWorldService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.mineralworldService.getAllMinerals().subscribe(
      (       data: any)=>{
        this.minerals=data;
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Angular 10 services:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MineralWorldService {
  getAllMinerals: any;



  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.getAllMinerals()
    {
     return this. http. get('data/minerals. json');
    }

   }
}
```

**the problems:**

Return type of constructor signature must be assignable to the instance type of the class.
Type 'Observable' is missing the following properties from type 'MineralWorldService': getAllMinerals, http

I would be very grateful if some can find the problem. If you need more information about the code, i will give you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `this.getAllMinerals()` from the service constructor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MineralWorldService {




  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

   

   }
    getAllMinerals()
    {
     return this.http.get('data/minerals.json');
    }
}
```